# Tracking multiple jquery ajax API requests with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have an increment that takes the ids and add them to url to make multiple ajax requests.

**js:**

```
for (x = 1; x <= val['id_count']; x++) {
 $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + x,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results, status, xhr) {
   },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#message").html("data: " + status + " " + error)
   }
 })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

what i trying to do here is to count the ids (urls) and show the progress of requests is progress bar and see what percent is complete and what percent is left. also how many total ids is there and how many request is completed from total.

in the other hand this is what i want to do **for example:**
[image]

**what i have done so far:**

```
for (x = 1; x <= val['id_count']; x++) {
 totalIDs = 0;
 totalIDs = x.length;
 $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + x,
    dataType: "json",
    xhr: function() {
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var progress = x / totalIDs * 100;
      $(".progress-bar").css({
          "width": progress + "%"
        });
      }
     return xhr;
    },
    success: function(results, status, xhr) {
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#message").html("data: " + status + " " + error)
   }
 })
}
```

ps: new to this

Comment: From the context of the screenshot, you're making 235 simultaneous AJAX requests...? Forget the progress bar, that's the problem you should look to fix first

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well, is there a limit? its looks crazy but the api don't give the information all at once so i have to loop trough them like this, and its a lot of requests and takes some time, so i need to see what's going on in background.

Comment: Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/ - you *could* use .ajaxSend() to increment "in progress" and .ajaxComplete to decrement it

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks man i did read the stuff, but i'm newbie so i'm gonna need little bit more explanation than that.

Comment: Looks like you could move your progress update to `success:` instead of `xhr:`  - `xhr:` is a bit advanced and it's unlikely you'd ever need to use this.   You could have a `var inprogress` then `inprogress++` as first line inside the `for` and `inprogress--` inside the `success` and calc your progress bar position `var progress = (totalIDs - inprogress)/totalIDs * 100` (or so)

Comment: @freedomn-m unfortunately it didn't work. or i made a mistake idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (x = 1; x <= val['id_count']; x++) {
 $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + x,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results, status, xhr) {
       if (inprogress < total_urls) {
         inprogress++;
         $("#tProgress").html(inprogress + ' / ' + total_urls + ' ✓');
         progress = Math.round(inprogress / total_urls * 100);
         $("#progress-bar").css({
            "width": progress + "%"
         });
         $("#progress-bar").html(progress + '%');
       }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#message").html("data: " + status + " " + error)
   }
 })
}
```